# What are the time complexities for finding pairs of numbers that when cubed add up to a certain value?

Tags: algorithm

The problem is as follows:

> Given an integer n, find all pairs that, when cubed, add up to n. (i.e. 1^3 + 12^3 = 1729, 9^3 + 10^3 = 1729, etc.)

I found two solutions for this:

1)

```
k = ceiling(cube root of n)
for i = 1 to k
    if (cube root of (n - i^3) % 1 == 0)
        print [i, j]
    end
end
```

2)

```
i = 1
j = ceiling(cube root of n)
while (i <= j)
    if (i^3 + j^3 == n)
        print [i++, j--]
    else if (i^3 + j^3 < n)
        i++
    else if (i^3 + j^3 > n)
        j-- 
    end
end
```

I believe both of these run at O(n), are there any advantages to one over the other?

Comment: The first has the problem that you're not describing how "cube root of (n - i^3) is an integer" is calculated.

Comment: I added an edit, does that look better?

Comment: how do you calculate "cube root of x" such that the result is exact when the answer is an integer? `pow(x, 1.0/3)` in most languages won't guarantee this.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_cbrt.htm

Answer (score 1):

In general, computing roots and similar exotic functions is an expensive operation, and coming up with exact numerical results so you can run a direct equality test is not always possible, so you need additional tests to see if you've come up with an exact integer solution. So your second piece of code is preferable. Technically it should start with I = 0.

Also, your optimal running time bound is O(n^(1/3)), not O(n).